# ob_start() flushed automatically when PHP script ends

Tags: php, ob-start

When I call `ob_start()` but not any of the end methods, the output is still being sent as if I would call `ob_end_flush()`. Is this always the case or does it depend on a PHP version or configuration parameter?

PHP 5.5.3

Answer (score 1):

[related Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123435/why-do-i-need-to-end-my-ob-start):

"...PHP flushes your output buffer implicitly when not using one of the ob_end_* functions."

so if you don't want that you need to use `ob_end_clean()`